# Error to compile after to add internationalization iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, internationalization, compilation

I have a problem. I have a iphone Project in Xcode 4, and I this project compiled perfect, but I have add internationalization to application and now if I try compile the application compile Failed, and give me the next error: `"Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"`

```
"ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Detail.tweets in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ApplicationName-cofhylaattdxjreknuzixudblevt/Build/Intermediates/ApplicationName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ApplicationName.build/Objects-normal/i386/Detail-7AC84D3333010C52.o and /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ApplicationName-cofhylaattdxjreknuzixudblevt/Build/Intermediates/ApplicationName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ApplicationName.build/Objects-normal/i386/Detail-A96D1FAB88823E17.o for architecture i386"
```

What I can do to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean for internationalization?

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally created a localized version of an .m file?

From the error message it sounds like you have two times the same file with your object.

---

If you did it on purpose because you wanted to localize all those `@"words"` in your code, you did it wrong.
In that case read the [iPhone Applications Localization Guide](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/).

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your helps! I did it on purpose, but I have see yoy link and this great! I got it!
Thank you for all.